# Add size (constraints) to SpriteNode

Tags: xcode, swift, constraints, sprite, skspritenode

I'm looking for a way to add height and width constraints to a SpriteNode.

```
let firstObject = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "card1")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    firstObject.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.5)
    addChild(firstObject)
}
```

This is my code at the moment - it shows the image but it is way to big, so now I want to do something like this;

```
firstObject.addConstraints(height and width)
```

But I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the size using its `size` property:

```
let width: CGFloat  = 100
let height: CGFloat = 100
firstObject.size    = CGSizeMake(width, height)
```